# Align div depends on the space avaialble

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I have the div alignment as show below. I don't need the formal table-like layout. I need DIV5 to use the space below DIV2 (marked in red). I'm using Bootstrap framework and I need a generic solution so that whereever I use that, the div elements will be align appropriately.

[image]

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a layout similar to Pinterest?

Comment: [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) could help you.

Comment: @Fraggy Yes. similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap's grid system isn't fluid, cascading or whatever you want to call it. I assume you have there two '.row' divs with columns and those accept only 12 columns on a row and that's it - rows won't overlap.

You should try using something like Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/), with or without bootstrap. With bootstrap you could create the Masonry grid inside of row > col-lg-12 like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Masonry grid plugin here.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried Masonry but it is not working when I load the page. It works fine when I resize the browser. I'm initializing with HTML as mentioned in http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Does it load the masonry code? Did you try initializing with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. I tried with JQuery initialization but facing the same issue

Comment: Are you sure you have the right file included and the initialization is put right? ID:s and classes are right? Did you create container for the masonry, ie. #mason-cont or did you use it to the col-lg-12?

Comment: Its working now. The image was not loaded initially and the mansonry function get called. I changed jquery onready() to window onload(). Everything works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of issue. Mosaic Flow came up handy and can be included in simple steps.

http://jquery-plugins.net/mosaic-flow-pinterest-like-responsive-image-grid

`<div class="mosaicflow__item">
    ....just include all <img> inside this DIV

</div>`
....include the plugin
`<script src="../lib/mosaicflow/jquery.mosaicflow.min.js"></script>`